# Sorting and comparing integer arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, compare

I am able to sort arrays, and able to compare arrays in separate steps, but when I attempt to do both in the same line, I get an error.  From the Java documentation, the sort method should return an array of the same type passed into it, and the equals method should return a boolean value.

What am I misunderstanding/misusing here?

Here is my code for testing the situation:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = {2,4,5,3,1};
        int[] arr2 = {4,3,2,1,5};

        if (Arrays.equals(Arrays.sort(arr1), Arrays.sort(arr2))) {  // Problem line
        System.out.println("Same contents");
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("Different contents");
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can see, I have created 2 arrays with the same contents.  I then call Arrays.equals(), and for its 2 arguments, I pass in the results of calling Arrays.sort() on each array.

When trying to compile, I get the following error:

```
test.java:9: error: 'void' type not allowed here
        if (Arrays.equals(Arrays.sort(arr1), Arrays.sort(arr2))) {
                                     ^
test.java:9: error: 'void' type not allowed here
        if (Arrays.equals(Arrays.sort(arr1), Arrays.sort(arr2))) {
                                                        ^
2 errors
shell returned 1
```

Comment: What is the [documented return type of Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-). The javadoc is your friend. Read it.

Comment: @JBNizet Yep, that'll do it.  I did have a read through it, but obviously confused my self into thinking an array was returned.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Arrays.sort()` method does not return the array;

Do this:

```
Arrays.sort(arr1);
Arrays.sort(arr2);
if (Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2)) {
// rest of code
```

Answer (score 2):

[Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) returns `void` type. You need valid array type to use  [Arrays.equals(int[] a,
             int[] a2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int[],%20int[]))